# How to retrieve INPUT value that belongs to an iteration table

Tags: table

This is the HTML code part that matters:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.data2}" var="var" indexVar="index">
                                    <tr id ="{!index}">
                                        <td class="slds-size_4-of-8">{!var.ProductName}</td>                                                                            
                                        <td class="slds-size_2-of-8">
                                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                                <input type="number" 
                                                       placeholder=""  
                                                       label="" 
                                                       name="{!index}"
                                                       required="true" 
                                                       class="slds-input" 
                                                       value= "{!var.Quantity}"/>
```

What I want later is to display that INPUT QUANTITY value for each line on that table. Im trying to update it but when I print using console.log it retrieves the standard value instead of the actual one.
Tested like this:
let listOI = cmp.get("v.data2");
console.log(listOI);

Comment: instead of `input` use `lightning:input` element.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks for the tip... it worked!